# Waiting for database connection before accepting requests

Tags: node.js, express, rxjs

The problem that I have is that my express server starts before the database connection is established. People can send requests to the application while the connection is not yet there for some time:

```
const app = express();
dbClient.connect()
  .subscribe(() => console.log('connection established!'));

module.exports = app.listen(8080, () => {
  console.log('the server is running');
});
```

The outcome of this is:

```
the server is running // some seconds break
connection established! // now everything works properly
```

How can I start listening to events only after the subscriber has been run?

Comment: Put the `app.listen(8080, ...)` call inside `subscribe()`

Comment: Then I can't export it

Answer (score 1):

The only way to ensure you are connected before to listen is to chain it. If you experience trouble about exporting the result is because you are mistaking import/export. Import/export should not have any impact on your system. Every actions should be triggered and not implied.

You should consider putting all your Express handling into a class and then use it in your controller. This way you could handle errors ... As example :

```
// File a.js

let instance = null;

export default class ServerApi {

  constructor() {
    if (instance) return instance;

    instance = this;

    return instance;
  }

  static getInstance() {
    return instance || new ServerApi();
  }

  startServer(callback) {
    const app = express();

    dbClient.connect()
      .subscribe(() => {
        console.log('connection established!');

        app.listen(8080, () => {
          console.log('the server is running');

          callback();
        });
      });
  }

  stopServer() { ... }

  getServerStatus() { ... }
};
```

---

```
// File controller.js

import ServerApi from 'a.js';

ServerApi.getInstance().startServer(() => {
  // handle error
  // handle success
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There are few ways to achieve this.

one a ways to wrap app.listen into observable

```
const app = express();

const connectApp = (port = 8080) => new Observable(observer => app.listen(port, () => {
  observer.next(app);
  observer.complete();
});

dbClient.connect()
   .pipe(
       tap(() => console.log('connection established!')),
       mergeMap(() => connectApp()),
       tap(() => console.log('the server is running')),
    )
  .subscribe(() => console.log('Enjoy'));
```